# _popen() returns nothing

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, popen

This is a **Qt** program. I am trying to run `gcc` command and get the result using `_popen`(on Windows). However, I get no output.

After debugging, I find that `gcc` command runs ok.

```cpp
void editor::on_action_Compile_triggered()
{
    QString str = "gcc \""+curFile+"\" -o \""+outputFile+"\" 2>&1"; //compile curFile 

    FILE *fp = _popen(str.toStdString().data(),"r");

    if (!fp)
    {
        ui->Log->setText("Error."); //Log is a text browser
    }
    else
    {
        QString tmpStr = "";
        char tmp[1024] = { 0 };

        while (fgets(tmp, 1024, fp) != NULL) //read fp
            tmpStr += (QString)tmp;

        ui->Log->setText(tmpStr); //print to screen
    }
    _pclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve your immediate problem but... since you're already using `Qt`, why not use [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) rather than `_popen`?  Could make life simpler.

Comment: Or do this to see what is a problem: `ui->Log->setText(std::strerror(errno));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, you are not having a problem. Your above code is working for me (as long as I declare a correct `curfile` and `outputFile`). **You are not having an ouput because gcc has successfully compiled the file. You may want to verify if the file called `outputFile` has been produced**. Indeed, when `gcc` succeeds, it does not ouput anything.

Otherwise, you might be having a problem with your `signal/slot` connexion which does not trigger the slot `on_action_Compile_triggered`(then please read on the complete code provided below)

To test it try to modify your `curFile` to point to an inexisting file and you will get an ouput error typical of `gcc`.

To check this, as for me, I created a `QmainWindow` with a `QPushButton` button (called pushbutton) and a `QtextEdit` (called `Log`). I provide my complete code below.

When I have an error (for instance the compiled file is not found. to emulate this, rename your `curFile` into a wrong file), I obtain this (using your code above).

[image]

When I do not have any error, I obtain nothing in the `QTextEdit`control but the `outputFile` executable file is produced by gcc in the directory:

Here is my code:

// QMainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void compile();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

// QMainWindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::compile);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    QObject::disconnect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::compile);

    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::compile()
{
    QString curFile("..\\..\\T0180694\\test.c");
    QString outputFile("..\\..\\T0180694\\test.exe");
    //copied all from your code
    QString str = "gcc \""+curFile+"\" -o \""+outputFile+"\" 2>&1"; //compile curFile

    FILE *fp = _popen(str.toStdString().data(),"r");

    if (!fp)
    {
        ui->Log->setText("Error."); //Log is a text browser
    }
    else
    {
        QString tmpStr = "";
        char tmp[1024] = { 0 };

        while (fgets(tmp, 1024, fp) != NULL) //read fp
            tmpStr += (QString)tmp;

        ui->Log->setText(tmpStr); //print to screen
    }
    _pclose(fp);
    //until here
}
```

//main.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```